# I want to convert sting ( associative array sting ) into associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i want to store associative array into a variable a as a string, and then convert the variable into array.

```
$var='"electirc_bill"=>array(
                                   "type" => "number",
                                    "required"=>"yes"
                                  ),
      "electirc_bill_per"=>array(
                                   "type" => "number",
                                    "required"=>"yes"
                                 ),                   
              "gass_bill"=>array(     
                                   "type" => "number",
                                    "required"=>"yes"
                                  )
    )';

    var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Use [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Convert the array to string:

```
$string = serialize($array);
```

Convert it back to an array:

```
$array = unserialize($string);
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment you seem to already have the array stored as a string and want to be able to convert it to an array. For that I would use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but be cautious when using it with any user input as it could lead to security vulnerabilities within your code.

I've made a small example using your code here: http://codepad.org/rPNXPBlW

```
$var = '$array_var = array("One" => array("1.1", "1.2"), "Two" => array("2.1", "‌​2.2"));';

eval($var);

echo $array_var['One'][0]; // Shows 1.1
```

Comment: thanks. i want take full associative array syntx as a string and want to convert into array.  <pre><code>$var='$array_var=array("One"=>array("1.1","1.2"),"Tow"=>array("2.1","2.2"));';</pre></code>

Comment: @navidaziz I suppose for that you could try `eval` but please read up about it's vulnerabilities first. Be cautious when using it with any user input. Here's an example: http://codepad.org/rPNXPBlW

Answer (score 0):

Use like below,

```
$json_str = json_encode($var); 

first then use json_decode($json_str); where required
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// save
file_put_contents('file.json', json_encode($array));

// load
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize and unserialize like this:

```
<?
$var=array("electirc_bill"=>array(
                 "type" => "number",
                 "required"=>"yes"
               ),
      "electirc_bill_per"=>array(
                 "type" => "number",
                 "required"=>"yes"
               ),                   
      "gass_bill"=>array(     
               "type" => "number",
               "required"=>"yes"
           )
    );
    var_dump($var);
    $string = serialize($var);
    var_dump($string);
    $array = unserialize($string);
    var_dump($array );
?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/gTJIrC9d)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Here i give suggestion to use this array will meet your requirement 

$name=array('parent1'=>array('childone'=>'harish','childtwo'=>'vignesh'),'parent2'=>array('childone'=>'our children'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($name);

foreach($name as $parents)
 {
  foreach($parents as $child)
   {
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($child);
   }
 }
```